# Cscope can't browse project source code

Tags: chromium

How can I use cscope tool for browsing project source code?

Currently I get the following error `cscope: cannot open file cscope.out` . My terminal output is shown below.

```
pase@pase:~/Projects/intel poky_rel/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/chromium/40.0.2214.91-r0/chromium-40.0.2214.91$ cd .. 
pase@pase:~/Projects/intel poky_rel/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/chromium/40.0.2214.91-ro$ cscope -d chromium-40.0.2214.91/  
cscope: cannot open file cscope.out 
pase@pase:~/Projects/intel poky_rel/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/chromium/40.0.2214.91-r0$
```

Answer (score 0):

cscope is an interactive, screen-oriented tool that allows the user to browse through C source files for specified elements of code.

cscope looks for a file that it can open, and if it finds one it creates a new file named cscope.out in the current directory. If cscope can't find a file that it can open, it displays this error message:

```
cscope: cannot open file cscope.out
```

Here is an example.

```
:~$ touch file-that-cscope-cant-open # make a new file that cscope can't open
:~$ cscope -d file-that-cscope-cant-open
cscope: cannot open file cscope.out
```

The `cscope -d chromium-40.0.2214.91/` command fails and outputs the error message `cscope: can't open file cscope.out` because `chromium-40.0.2214.91/` is not a permissible filename, so a file named `chromium-40.0.2214.91/` does not exist. Because a file named `chromium-40.0.2214.91/` does not exist, cscope can't open that file. Maybe you got confused about the `-d` option which does not stand for directory.

You can run the `ls` command to check if there are any source files in the current directory. By  default, cscope examines the C (.c and .h), lex (.l), and yacc (.y) source files in the current directory, and it can also be used for C++ code.